# What am I doing wrong with this lcm python code?

Tags: python, recursion, lcm

Here is my code:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if a%b == 0:
        return b
        print b

    elif b%a == 0:
        return a
        print a
    else:
        if a > b:
            gcd(a%b,b)
        elif b > a:
            gcd(b%a,a)
        else:
            return a
            print a
def lcm(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return a
    else:
        y = gcd(a,b)
        return (a*b)/y
        print (a*b)/y
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting an error because apparently `y = gcd(a,b)` is a `NoneType` and it must be an integer. But from what I see it is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `return` in front of your recursive calls to `gcd`. Otherwise it returns `None` if it ends up in one of those branches.

The `print` statements after your `return`s are never reached.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the code can be much simpler for `gcd` and `lcm`, since some of your base cases overlap.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)

def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b / gcd(a, b)
```

Don't forget: for recursive functions, you have to use `return` to link recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

once a return statement is executed , the control exits from the function call. So your print statements are never executed . You should write print statement before return . Also doing a dry run with pen and paper would help the flow of execution.